# cooked it well as you wanted

Tags: meaning, punctuation, adverbial-phrases

a. I cooked the pie in a clay dish as you wanted.

b. I cooked the pie in a clay dish, as you wanted.

Is there a difference in the meanings of the above sentences?

Does the comma change anything?

I think in (a), I cooked it in a clay dish and in the manner you wanted.
In (b) you wanted it to be cooked in clay dish and that is how I cooked it.

============================

​c. I cooked the chicken well as you wanted.

d. I cooked the chicken well, as you wanted.

Is there a difference in the meanings of the above sentences?
Does the comma change anything?

In theory we should have the same difference we have between (a) and (b), but I am not sure that difference exists here.
I am not sure (c) is even correct.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't find the versions without commas idiomatic. A native speaker would say something like "...just the way you wanted it".

Comment: Thank you so much for all your kind replies. Would you use 'just the way you wanted it' with a comma or not? Will the absence of a comma change the meaning?

Comment: Whatever final phrase you choose, I would find them unidiomatic without the comma.